# List of model fields with missing values nicely formatted in Django template

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I'm trying to make a view in Django to list each entry in a model and any of the fields that are missing values. The template is a table: one column is a specific field and the other column is a list of the fields with missing values. I have a working version, but the missing fields are just strung together, and I'd like to have them nicely formatted with commas in between.

```
#models.py
class exif(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey('image', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    copyright = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

```
#views.py
def exif_export(request):
    exif_records = serializers.serialize("python", exif.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'exif_export.html', {'exif_records': exif_records})
```

```
#exif_export.html
<table>
<tr>
  <th>File</th>
  <th>Missing Exif Fields</th>
</tr>
{% for record in exif_records %}
<tr>
  <td>
  {% for field, value in record.fields.items %}
    {% if field == 'filename' %}
      {{ value }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  </td>
  <td>
  {% for field, value in record.fields.items %}
    {% if not value %}
        {{ field }}, <!-- This comma makes a trailing comma at the end of the list -->
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Is there a good way to format those fields into a nice list? Right now it'll look like:
`artist, comment,`
Whereas it'd be nice if it looked like:
`artist, comment`
Or even better:
`Artist, Comment`
Do I have to make a dictionary or something in the view and pass that to the template? Or is there a way to make a list of fields missing values in Django and/or Python in general? It'd be nice if the template could just handle it, I just can't think of any other way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `{{ field|capfirst }}` for capitalizing the first letter, to remove the trailing comma you could do something like

```
  {% for field, value in record.fields.items %}
    {% if not value and field != last_field %}
        {{ field|capfirst }},
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  {{ last_feild|capfirst }}
```

and pass `last_field` in somewhere (probably in the model).

Alternatly, you could write a templatetag to do this for you.

Comment: `capfirst` is great, didn't know about that. Not sure how to get `last_field` because it could change with each row.

Comment: you could do (in the backend) something like: `{'fields': fields, 'last_field': fields.pop()}`